# Python - Data Scraping - Sam's Club web scraper code seems to be working fine but is printing N/A fill values where it shouldn't be?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-mining

I am trying to understand why this Sam's Club web scraper code seems to be picking up N/A fill values when the website provides a value for the code to scrape.

I have provided three different URLs at the top that replicate the problem to varying degrees.

General brand searches like Oreo and Reese's seem to work pretty well, but for some reason there are items that have a price on the website where the code fills in N/A for the price.

Then if you try an overall category search like #url3 for Sodas, more than half of the prices are filled as N/A.

**QUESTIONS:**

**1.)** Why is the code scraping SOME of the data correctly, but not all of it?

**2.)** Is this an error in terms of how the code is looping and filling in the N/A values, or is this due to Sam's Club's website/server architecture?

Thank you in advance, code is below:

```
import requests
import itertools
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url = "https://www.samsclub.com/s/oreo"                                      #url1
#url = "https://www.samsclub.com/s/reeses"                                   #url2
#url = 'https://www.samsclub.com/b/soda/2080101?xid=cat1499-beve_vnav_5_3'   #url3





headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'Cookie': 'localeEditionShown_en=true; permutive-session=^%^7B^%^22session_id^%^22^%^3A^%^22e5386dfb-c58a-4882-b0e1-2cc2d9518982^%^22^%^2C^%^22last_updated^%^22^%^3A^%^222017-11-22T19^%^3A10^%^3A04.522Z^%^22^%^7D; visid_incap_774904=4xMirl1lRNOgrnN+Sm9S1zNx61kAAAAAREIPAAAAAACAsmaAAbBYMBjQTCqLf/D6wOVO4hdnKjIF; incap_ses_151_774904=/LX+SNRqsR8SzJi7p3YYAjKgGloAAAAApdQygw8VYBxbv/wvl7Be7A==; _gat=1; _gat_subdomainTracker=1; _ga=GA1.2.1522498341.1508602188; _gid=GA1.2.1243543827.1511694421'
}


page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

product_names = [p.getText(strip=True) for p in soup.find_all("div", class_="sc-pc-title-medium")]
product_prices = [p["title"].split()[-1] for p in soup.find_all("span", class_="Price-group")]

results = {k: v for k, v in itertools.zip_longest(product_names, product_prices, fillvalue="N/A")}

for product, price in results.items():
    print(product, price)
```

Answer (score 1):

**QUESTIONS:**

**1.)** Why is the code scraping SOME of the data correctly, but not all of it?

You mean for example the prices & N/A values? Well you are correct some of the data prices are being scraped correctly & some are not & the reason behind this actually is just on the code or algorithm of the scraping program.

**Let's say for this instance.**

```
Coca-Cola (12oz / 35pk) $10.48  
Mountain Dew (12 oz. cans, 36 pk.) $10.48
```

[image: products]

Now as you can see on the image this is scraped incorrectly as I should say cause the `Cola-Cola (12oz / 35pk)` should not be `$10.48` and it should be `N/A` or `None`. Now again why is this happening? There isn't an error on the code actually (when you run the program it works fine as it is), it's just way the algorithm is written to scrape this site, it's just **NOT PROPERLY WELL WRITTEN**.

Think of this code right here & what does it do? It just gets the `product names` and `product prices` right? It just does that! but there are no `constraints`. Now what do I mean by `constraints`?, kind of like a condition as for example what if a certain product does not have a price? What will it do? Well base on the code here it DOES NOT HANDLE THAT POSSIBLE OUTCOME, it just gets whatever `tag` it finds based on its `class` & returns it to you in a `list` and that's it, the program doesn't actually handle possible outcomes like as I've said if there are no prices (that is why there are times you get data where the prices doesn't correspond to the site).

```
product_names = [p.getText(strip=True) for p in soup.find_all("div", class_="sc-pc-title-medium")]
product_prices = [p["title"].split()[-1] for p in soup.find_all("span", class_="Price-group")]
```

2.) Is this an error in terms of how the code is looping and filling in the N/A values, or is this due to Sam's Club's website/server architecture?

I would say **it's an error in terms of how the code is looping to get all the prices correctly**. There's really not much of relevance of the site's server architecture rather more on the website html code cause that is where basically we look at in order to properly scrape these data.

Now another question that I think might sink in is:

### Well, how can this web scraping program correctly scrape the data?

You're going to have to fix it and make some changes out of it, fix the scraping algorithm because as I've observe when I did some test runs on the `3 urls` yet indeed you are correct it doesn't get the data properly and I suggest it's just on the scraping algorithm on how it scrapes the data.